# Use Google Cloud Storage from PHP application (not hosted on App Engine)

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm using Google Cloud Storage for media. My website is stored elsewhere. I want to serve medias for client users (through web browser), but I don't want to use public images (I want "keys"). I think it's possible on app engine (building URL), but my question is:

Is it possible to build URL to Google Cloud Storage stored medias from another server with PHP ? Or **is there an API for calling Google Cloud Storage if my site is not on App Engine ?**

Hope it's clear enough. Sorry, I did not found answer (I'm a new user).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the [google-api-php-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) library can be used outside of AppEngine. There is a [PHP Example Tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/json-api-php-samples) to help you get started.